# CM3 - How can I use USB_OTG on carrier board? How does this differ from CMIO board?

Tags: usb, pi-zero-w, compute-module-3

Currently trying to figure out how to setup USB_OTG on the CM3 using my carrier board.

I posted on the RPI forums and got an answer which was to connect pin 4 (ID) on a usb micro AB connector directly to the USB_OTGID pin on the CM3 which I proceeded to correct in my board schematic.

I'm curious as if this literally the only thing I have to do or am I missing something else?

When I looked into the CMIO board I was presented with a few answers and wondered if any of them would relate to changes I'd have to make with my carrier design:

- Jumper to 3v3
- Downloading & implementing new dwc2 driver

Can someone also explain the OTG cables, I understand that micro B will place the device into peripheral mode whilst micro a will turn it into host mode; however I'm equally confused when I see tutorials for the Pi zero on OTG and they only use a micro B cable and allows the pi zero to be powered and also be in slave mode to access the terminal. [See here](http://www.circuitbasics.com/raspberry-pi-zero-ethernet-gadget/)